# Restrict Source Access to SQL Server Service Account

Tags: sql-server, security, service-accounts

I have an Audit requirement to ensure that the service accounts (that connect to SQL Server) are not used by anyone but the by the APPLICATION SERVER itself.

All other connections attempts must be refused including access via SSMS. I also wanted to avoid doing it via Network such as Proxy, etc.

Can you provide me with some clues?

Comment: Our auditors haven't asked for this yet, hope they don't talk to yours..

Comment: Some audit requirements expect you to prevent certain unauthorized access. Others require that you have policies & procedures in place to identify and deal with unauthorized access. This sounds like a case where the latter would be a more reasonable & more feasible approach. Is it acceptable to your auditors that you can mitigate and track unauthorized access? Or do they expect you to prevent it?

Comment: What type of account does your application server use (virtual service account, Managed Service Account, regular domain account, ...)? Where is the application server executing, on the same machine as your SQL or on a different machine?

Comment: Put a firewall in place and whitelist the servers? There are also login triggers you can use, which I presume would expose the NT login being used, and then allow you to fail the login in attempt based on your criteria.